# Is there a way to check if a couple of inputs are unique in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, unique

## update

What I have is a table with these columns:

```
- ID
- production_year
- type
```

If the `type` is already present in the table with the value the user wants to pass, check if `production_year` is already present too, but fail the validation ONLY if these values are present in the same record. Otherwise let the user to store this record.

I'm trying to check the uniqueness of a couple of fields in the same record...

I've seen the documentation about the conditional validation, but I didn't quite find the answer there.

## the code

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // I'd like to check the uniqueness of both of them. In the same record
        'production_y' => 'required|unique',
        'fk_type' => 'required|unique',     
    ];
}
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You want to validate "input-A" to a column in your db table and "input-B" to the same column in your db table?

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? If you put the unique rule on both it should work..

Comment: I think that will determine the uniqueness of both separately when what he likely wants is to determine if they are unique together.  It would be like creating 2 unique keys in a database 1 for each column as opposed to one unique key for 2 columns.

Comment: It's easy with models, if you have two models then you can use unique:modelName in validate
`$this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'unique:posts|unique:files',
]);`

Comment: I've updated my question. I'm trying to check the uniqueness on a couple of columns in the same record. But if A != B let the user store the record

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN I've updated the question with the code

Comment: `$cars= DB::table('cars')->unique(array('production_year', 'type'))->get();` reffering to [https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_unique](this) but i don't know how to implement it with validate

Comment: Where should I put this? In the controller? I've never used this approach

Comment: Yes, but i'm almost sure that it's also possible with validate, check [http://laravel.io/forum/11-03-2015-laravel-unique-validation-on-multiple-columns-for-unique-relations?page=1#reply-28403](this) 
`'production_year' => 'required|unique:table_name,production_year,NULL,id,type,'.$type`
something like this

Comment: actually @HilmiErdemKEREN has given me the right way, but I'd like now to understand that validation syntax. Can someone explain it to me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Laravel 5.3 Update:

Now, you can generate the same rule fluently using the Rule (`\Illuminate\Validation\Rule`) class.

`NULL,id` *part of the string way is no more required.* See:

```
public function rules()
{
    $type = $this->get('fk_type');

    return [
        'production_y' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('your_table', 'production_year')->where(function($query) {
                $query->where('type', $type);
            }),
        ],
    ];
}
```

### Original Answer

Can't test right now, can you try:

```
public function rules()
{
    $type = $this->get('fk_type');

    return [
        'production_y' => "required|unique:your_table,production_year,NULL,id,type,{$type}",
        // ...
    ];
}
```

Explaination:

1. `unique:your_table` Set the table for the unique check.
2. `,production_year` This matches with `production_y`.
3. `,NULL,id` check all the records.

   3.1. if you use like `{$id},id` it will check uniqueness except the record with the `{$id}`,
4. `,type,{$type}` and the type should be `{$type}`

That will produce sth. like (not exact query, just to express the idea):

`select count(*) from your_table where production_year = $product_y and where type = $type and where id <> null`

Comment: let me check. Thanks

Comment: Wow! This is actually working! Can you explain me better what this validation is doing? It will come in really handy in the future!

Comment: I see, now I'm starting to understand. And $this->get('fk_type') is working on the request right? It's storing the foreign key from the input?

Comment: Yes. $this is the Request class itself. And the get method comes from the Request class of Symfony which the Laravel FormRequest extends. Like Input::get().

Comment: Thank you! You've saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

if someone cames from laravel 8, i tried this and it worked !!
for me i need to check the uniqueness of (category_id,subcategory_id) which mean you can find (1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3) but you cant find similar couple !!

```
'category' => "required|unique:tickets,category_id,NULL,id,subcategory_id,{$request->input('subcategory')}"
```